# \r and \b not working in Python? (how to erase a line?)

Tags: python

In the new python /r and /b don't work (I am using windows 10 and repl.it)

Is there an easy way to make a line look like its backspacing itself?

```
import sys
print("FAILED...")
sys.stdout.write("\033[F") #back to previous line
sys.stdout.write("\033[K") #clear line
print("SUCCESS!")
```

doesn't work either `/\
                  |`

Comment: \r returns the cursor to the start of the line, like pressing HOME key. \b sends cursor back one, like pressing left arrow. They don't erase the character that is there. Print a line of spaces or something, to overwrite what exists

Comment: It won't work. You can't change the previous line. You can only change the current line. If it does work anywhere, it's more like an exception rather than a rule.

Comment: ```print('\roverwriting..', end='')```? You cannot erase a line. However, you can overwrite a line if you don't print a newline from the previous print

Answer (score 2):

The interpretation of the control characters depends entirely on the rendering engine for the target device.  For instance, if you're writing to a paper-based output -- say, an archaic teletype 33 terminal -- there's no way you can erase text.  Device drivers differ in what controls they support and how.

You need to check the documentation for the device, whether an xterminal, a command window, or whatever -- how does that channel interpret those characters?